# How to download a file using SharePoint REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

How to download a file using SharePoint REST API?

The following document doesn't contain the downloading related information

Refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx

Kindly provide your inputs for downloading a file from SharePoint REST API.

Comment: So what data **did** you get back when you called a One File endpoint? And what other related information did you expect?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the binaryStringResponseBody to true to downstream a file from SharePoint.

```
var info = {
    url: appwebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Test/Shared Documents/" + sourcefile.get_name() + "')/$value?@target='myhosturl'",

    binaryStringResponseBody: true,
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function () { alert('error'); }

}
```

If you're facing any issue please follow the below link:
http://www.techmikael.com/2013/07/how-to-copy-files-between-sites-using.html

Comment: Please mark this as the answer, if you're satisfied with the response.

Comment: To simplify the URL and assuming you're not going from the Add-In Web to the Hostweb but call SharePoint directly using an oAuth Bearer Token you could also just go for: /_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Test/Shared%20Documents/test.jpg')/$value

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to pass this work to sharepoint. With the answer of Arut you can use the following path once you get the file endpoint 
http://spsite/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=http://spsite/Documents/sample.docx