# Retrieving files from sharepoint returns empty value array

Tags: development, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, document

I am able to retrieve list and list items just fine:

```
var client2 = new RestClient("https://preactdk.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('mylist')/items");
client2.Timeout = -1;
var request2 = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request2.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {tokenData.access_token}");
request2.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
IRestResponse response2 = client2.Execute(request2);
```

However, when I try to retrieve the file within "Documents" in the "testfolder" directory via `_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('testfolder/asdf.txt')/Files` I get the following result:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": []
    }
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

I wish to retrieve the URL of the `asdf.txt` file & then download it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the REST endpoint in below format using **GetFileByServerRelativeUrl** instead of **GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl**:

```
https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name/{file_name}')
```

**Example**:

Endpoint:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/SPConnect/Shared%20Documents/Document.docx')
```

**Output**:

```
<m:properties>
    <d:CheckInComment></d:CheckInComment>
    <d:CheckOutType m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:CheckOutType>
    <d:ContentTag>{03DE5AB8-5EA1-4F30-85A0-D6CDA53CA8EF},14,17</d:ContentTag>
    <d:CustomizedPageStatus m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:CustomizedPageStatus>
    <d:ETag>"{03DE5AB8-5EA1-4F30-85A0-D6CDA53CA8EF},14"</d:ETag>
    <d:Exists m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:Exists>
    <d:IrmEnabled m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IrmEnabled>
    <d:Length m:type="Edm.Int64">27544</d:Length>
    <d:Level m:type="Edm.Byte">1</d:Level>
    <d:LinkingUri>https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/Shared%20Documents/Document.docx?d=w03de5ab85ea14f3085a0d6cda53ca8ef</d:LinkingUri>
    <d:LinkingUrl>https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/Shared Documents/Document.docx?d=w03de5ab85ea14f3085a0d6cda53ca8ef</d:LinkingUrl>
    <d:MajorVersion m:type="Edm.Int32">6</d:MajorVersion>
    <d:MinorVersion m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:MinorVersion>
    <d:Name>Document.docx</d:Name>
    <d:ServerRelativeUrl>/sites/SPConnect/Shared Documents/Document.docx</d:ServerRelativeUrl>
    <d:TimeCreated m:type="Edm.DateTime">2020-01-29T08:00:16Z</d:TimeCreated>
    <d:TimeLastModified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2020-02-25T06:49:58Z</d:TimeLastModified>
    <d:Title></d:Title>
    <d:UIVersion m:type="Edm.Int32">3072</d:UIVersion>
    <d:UIVersionLabel>6.0</d:UIVersionLabel>
    <d:UniqueId m:type="Edm.Guid">03de5ab8-5ea1-4f30-85a0-d6cda53ca8ef</d:UniqueId>
</m:properties>
```

**Documentation**: [Working with folders and files with REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest)

Comment: Thank you so much. That solved it. I also use the header `Accept: application/json;odata=verbose`. Can you check this result with this header? how do I then download the actual file? there should be a way to build a URL or something

Comment: when I try without that header to get XML back, my <d:LinkingUri> and <d:LinkingUrl> are empty

Comment: Edit: found it, have to add /$value at the end

Comment: You're right. You need to use `/$value` to get the file contents/value.

Comment: do you know why it downloads without a file extension?

Comment: Are you downloading the file via script or on button/link click from browser? You need to provide the filename & extension. check examples at [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-files-by-using-rest). Also, alternative way to download file is to pass file URL to `http://siteUrl/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=<fileUrl>`. Check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/210494/how-to-download-a-file-using-sharepoint-rest-api) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I used "siteAbsoluteUrl".

```
let siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
let url = siteUrl + "/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('<relative path to the folder>')/Files";
```

When I use "webAbsoluteUrl", then it gives me the files from the folder.

```
let siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
let url = siteUrl + "/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('<relative path to the folder>')/Files";
```